# Can I have different pygame.set_repeat() values for different keys?

Tags: python, pygame

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 1)

def game():
    game_running = True

while game_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player.move_left(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player.move_right(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            player.move_up(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player.move_down(3)
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            create_bullet()
```

The pygame.key.set_repeat() value here allows me to move the player sprite smoothly, but also causes way more bullets than I'd want to be created if the player were to hold space. To prevent this, I'd want space key to have a set_repeat value of (1, 500). Would it be possible to accomplish this without creating a solution of my own?

Comment: There are a lot of potential approaches to this sort of thing, and I think you are probably better served by trying to follow along with a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better served setting a timer on when a bullet was created, and not allow another bullet to be created for `BULLET_COOLDOWN` milliseconds.  This is fairly easy to implement with the function `pygame.time.get_ticks()` which returns an ever-increasing number of milliseconds.

```
BULLET_COOLDOWN = 500    # milliseconds between bullets
bullet_time     = 0      # time when bullet fired

...

if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()                 # what time is it?
    if ( bullet_time + BULLET_COOLDOWN < time_now ):   # has cooldown past?
        create_bullet()                                   
        bullet_time = time_now                         # remember for next firing
```